# my site hijacked, added url on my site and can't be redirected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site hacked and they add url with string "bitsofev" for example:
http://example.com/~bitsofev
http://example.com/~bitsofev/apple.de

Check here for real sample
https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=bitsofev&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0CBsQvgUoAWoVChMI7LnMiOvIxwIVQpGOCh1T2wC6&biw=1570&bih=899

I tried to redirect it to homepage with htaccess but not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)~bitsofev(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I tried the same code to redirect other string and it works fine, but not "bitsofev" string. weird.

Best I can do for this is to block on robot.txt but its not solving the problem. What can I do for this?? Where can I fix the original problem? How to redirect it to homepage if I can't find the source?

Additional info: I searched on MySQL db, and I can't find 'bitsofev'.

Comment: Is there a user account on your server for a user called "bitsofev"?

Comment: no, only 2 accounts here, none of them are "bitsofev"

Comment: Are there really only 2 accounts? If so that's highly insecure as the webserver should run as a different account to the administrator (root) and the user account (you). Assuming this is a *nix box, what does the shell command `finger bitsofev` report?

Comment: 2 users only because this is small article based site. How to do shell command? Sorry i don't know anything about server, this is on shared hosting. So your opinion this is server issue? not my wordpress issue?

Comment: Sounds like server misconfiguration - contact your hosting support team.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Someone may have added the "/~bitsofev/apple.de" url to my site. A web analytics app track visitors and the content viewed at my site. Like you I don't have many users. Originally I thought that the "/~bitsofev/apple.de" was first accessed sometime last month. I originally also noticed that one of the user at my site registered at nearly the same time. My first thought was to temporarily deny this user access to signing into the site (and interacting with mysql db) while I investigated if this user uploaded a malicious file to the mysql db or exploited some error in the code that I was not aware of. However, I subsequently discovered (I hadn't been monitoring it regularly) a message from google regarding the url "~bitsofev/apple.de" in my admin inbox which predates the web analytics data and the user's registration that I originally thought may have been suspicious.

I will let you know everything further that I ascertain.

I meant to post this as a comment and not an answer.  I apologize.

Comment: Last night (after 9:00 PM – September 28, 2015) I renamed the main index.php at the my site to index.html

Immediately after making the change I checked the "/~bitsofev/apple.de" url and found that it was no longer functional and I received a ERROR 404 – PAGE NOT FOUND

It appears that someone was able to hack (or exploit some segment of the code) the php.index file.

For the time being I am going use index.html file rather than index.php

After I learn more about the problem that I was creating (my error alone) in php I plan to again use index.php

Comment: Add the the following to your .htaccess                                                                RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ~bitsofev/apple.de($|\ |\?)  [NC]  
RewriteRule .*  - [F]

Answer (score 0):

Add the the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ~bitsofev/apple.de($|\ |\?)  [NC]  
RewriteRule .*  - [F]
```

This will block (403 error) the file and url from being accessed. However, it wont specifically correct the problem.

I believe that was is really happening is that you are using shared hosting at Hostgator and IP 108.167.182.250 / 108.167.182.251

**bitsofev** (the owner of the site **http://bitsofeverything.net/**) is another user on the Hostgator shared hosting.

For example, go their website and after .net/ type in the tilde "~" symbol and the your user name (your hostgator user name), e.g, **~username**

If I'm correct you'll then see your own website. You can then add a / and folders/files and see those, as well.

This is because Hostgator enables (by default) `mod_userdir` (Apache server).

The only part I don't understand yet is the **apple.de** because it doesn't appear to be a folder or file at bitsofeverything.net/

At any rate, I've been writing about this for a couple of months (trying to understand it better) at:

[Justinbailey.info: What is /~bitsofev/apple.de added url? Hacked, hacker hacking.](http://justinbailey.info/2015/09/20/what-is-bitsofevapple-de-added-url-hacked-hacker-hacking/)

Comment: Is this really working? because I think the ~bitsofev have higher authority than htaccess. I already moved my site to another webhost because this bitsofev reported as malicious/phishing, I don't want google to punish my site.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for blocking `~bitsofev/apple.de` but it will not work just for `~bitsofev` by itself because `~bitsofev` is a username on the same shared hosting server at Hostgator where you site was hosted before.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to block other usernames on Hostgator shared servers you would need to contact Hostgator tech support and request that they disable `mod_userdir` for your account.  Additionally, you could also resolve the problem by not using **shared server** at Hostgator and instead use Hostgator **vps** or Hostgator **dedicated servers**.

Comment: Read more about `mod_userdir` at Hostgator: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/mod_userdir